# (Ruby) How to import the data from my XML file into SQLite tables

Tags: ruby, xml, sqlite, nokogiri

I want to import the data from an XML file into my SQLite tables. What should I do? I really need some help.
Here is my code, I don't know what's wrong with these.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
class AddCoursesData < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    Course.delete_all
    courses = Nokogiri::XML(File.open("courses.xml"))

    courses.css('course').each do |node|
      children = node.children

      Course.create(
        acode: node['acode'],
        code: node['code'],
        sgid: node['sgid'],
        name: children.css('name').inner_text,
        ects: children.css('ects').inner_text,
        year: children.css('year').inner_text,
        period: children.css('period').inner_text,
        institute: children.css('institute').inner_text,
        description: children.css('description').inner_text,
        timetable: children.css('timetable').inner_text,
        lecture_material: children.css('lecture_material').inner_text,
        goals: children.css('goals').inner_text,
        participant_count: children.css('participant_count').inner_text,
        specialities: children.css('specialities').inner_text,
        examination: children.css('examination').inner_text
      )

    end
  end

  def down
  end
end
```

and then I input

```
>rake db:migrate
```

it says

```
"rake aborted!
 cannot load such file -- nokogiri
 D:in 'migrate'
 Tasks: TOP=> db:migrate"
```

I have installed nokogiri. I really don't know how to import these data. So can you help me with this? Thank you very much!!

And here is my rubygems environment

```
D:\BitNami\rubystack\rubywork\UvAcourses>gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.0.3
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2012-05-25 patchlevel 231) [i386-mingw32]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: D:/BitNami/rubystack/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: D:/BitNami/rubystack/ruby/bin/ruby.exe
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: D:/BitNami/rubystack/ruby/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-mingw32
  - GEM PATHS:
     - D:/BitNami/rubystack/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
     - C:/Users/Lulu/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
```

Comment: Do you have Nokogiri installed?

Comment: Yes. I think so. "Successfully installed nokogiri-1.6.0-x86-mingw32
unable to convert "\xE6" to UTF-8 in conversion from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 to GBK for CHANGELOG.ja.rdoc, skipping
unable to convert "\xC3" to UTF-8 in conversion from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 to GBK for CHANGELOG.rdoc, skipping
unable to convert "\xE2" to UTF-8 in conversion from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 to GBK for ext/nokogiri/xml_node_set.c, skipping
unable to convert "\xE9" to UTF-8 in conversion from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 to GBK for README.ja.rdoc, skipping
1 gem installed"

Comment: Is this part of a Rails app? If so you likely need to add Nokogiri to your `Gemfile`.

Comment: AH!!! Thank you very much!!!!! I added this in my Gemfile and it succeeded!!!! Thank you!!!! HAHAHAHAH!!!!

Comment: checkout this sax parsing options, http://amolnpujari.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/reading_huge_xml-rb/ New OX ruby parser seems to be 5 times faster than Nokogiri, https://gist.github.com/amolpujari/5966431

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How old is your Ruby?

Prior to Ruby 1.8.7 we had to start our require list with:

```
require 'rubygems'
```

because RubyGems was not part of Ruby's standard library. If we didn't do that we would fail to find all external (non-core and non-standard-lib) gems.

Now days that's not necessary.

Other ways to tell if Nokogiri is installed are to type these at the command-line:

```
gem list nokogiri
which nokogiri
```

The first looks through the internal list of installed gems. The second asks Linux or Mac OS OS if it sees the "nokogiri" command, which is installed by the gem.

Comment: I've seen my nokogiri gem in the first step. But in the second step, mine is windows7, what should i do?

Comment: Append the output of `gem env` to your question.